# Calculating transaction fee for various coins(BTC, DOGE, LTC, BCH, ADA, ETH)

Tags: blockchain

I want to calculate the transaction fees before initiating a blockchain transaction request. For BTC, I was able to estimate the fee using this formula:

```
const networkSpeed = 8;(8 satoshis per byte)
((inputTxCount * 180 + outputTxCount * 34 + 10 - inputTxCount) * networkSpeed) / 100000000
```

I want to estimate fee for other coins like LTC, DOGE, BCH, ADA, ETH. I don't want to use any external-api call to calculate the fee, I want to do it manually.

Can somebody please tell me, What formula do I need to use for estimating the fee for the above coins?

Thank you

Comment: This is different for each network, which makes this question too broad IMHO. Your best bet is to check the coins' / networks' documentations. I'd seriously reconsider using a library or API though. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the suggestion, any library or API service provider you suggest, which provides an estimated fee for the above coins?